# Issues with Tkinter in having buttons in the secondary (second) window by click button in main window

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have now been able to generate a code which pops up a new window with entries, when I click the button "Test" in the first Window. However, I am having problems creating buttons in the second window. The entries are created, but no buttons. Also as an additional question, I will like to add to this if it can be possible, that when I click the button Test in 1st window, the second window with entries/text/button pops up and the first window is killed?

*The way I have it now, it pops an error to me saying "'MySecondGUI' object has no attribute 'buttonPressed2"*

Help will be very much appreciated.

I have pasted my code below:

**GUI_VIEW FILE ( gui_view.py)**

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import Tk


class MyMainGUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, controller):

       tk.Frame.__init__(self)
       self.pack()
       self.controller = controller

       self.Button1=tk.Button(self)
       self.Button1["text"]= "Test"
       self.Button1["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed1
       self.Button1.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2)


class MySecondGUI(tk.Toplevel):

       def __init__(self):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)


        self.outputLabel2 = tk.Label(self)
        self.outputLabel2["text"] = ("Enter Value")
        self.outputLabel2.grid(row=5,rowspan=2)

        self.entrySpace2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entrySpace2.grid(row=8,column=0,rowspan=2)

        self.Button2=tk.Button(self)
        self.Button2["text"]= "Try Me"
        self.Button2["command"] = self.buttonPressed2
        self.Button2.grid(row=14,column=0,rowspan=2)enter code here
```

**GUI MAIN CONTROLLER FILE**

```
import tkinter as tk 

import gui_view # the VIEW file


class MainControl:

    def __init__(self):   
      self.root = tk.Tk()
      self.root.geometry('550x200')
      self.view = gui_view_temp.MyMainGUI(self)
      self.view.mainloop()

    def newWindow(self):

      self.viewNew = gui_view.MySecondGUI()
      self.viewNew.geometry('300x400')
      self.newDisplay = tk.Label(self.newWin, text='Test Mode')
      self.viewNew.mainloop()
      self.newDisplay.pack()

    def buttonPressed1(self):

         self.newWindow()

    def buttonPressed2(self):

         pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    c = MainControl()
```

Comment: Well, your `MySecondGUI` class does not have an attribute `self.buttonPressed2`, you should get it from the `MainControl` class, like you did for your `MyMainGUI` class...

Comment: Hi Toti08, I did not get it. Can you please elaborate and provide a code snippet. How can I get it from the MainControl Class? The issue is that I do not want to pop both the windows at the same time. Only when Button 1 is pressed the second window should pop up along with entry test/buttons..

Comment: look at the answer you got, there you'll find the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## 1st part of your question

Your button is not appearing because the class `MySecondGUI` has to have access to the main root ("controller") too. Modify the constructor of `MySecondGUI` as follows:

```
def __init__(self, controller):

    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    self.controller = controller  # Add controller too

    self.outputLabel2 = tk.Label(self)
    self.outputLabel2["text"] = ("Enter Value")
    self.outputLabel2.grid(row=5, rowspan=2)

    self.entrySpace2 = tk.Entry(self)
    self.entrySpace2.grid(row=8, column=0, rowspan=2)

    self.Button2 = tk.Button(self)
    self.Button2["text"] = "Try Me"
    # Button referenced to the controller
    self.Button2["command"] = self.controller.buttonPressed2
    self.Button2.grid(row=14, column=0, rowspan=2)
```

Then, call it from the main class as:

```
self.viewNew = gui_view.MySecondGUI(self)
```

## 2nd part of your question

Regarding your second question, you cannot kill the main window since it is the root of your program (the second one is just a `Toplevel` widget). You could hide it by using the following line of code at the beginning of the function `newWindow`:

```
self.root.withdraw()
```

If you want to use the root window again (you should), you can use the `deiconify` method:

```
self.root.deiconify()
```